# ajax validation error message

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

how to add my own message for the client side validation in JSF.

```
<div class="ui-grid-row">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-3" align="left">
        <h:outputLabel for="cmpny" value="Company Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
        <p:inputText id="cmpny" value="#{userData.cmpny}">
            <f:validateLength minimum="10" />
            <p:ajax execute="currentInput" update="company" event="blur" />
        </p:inputText>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-1" />
    <div class="ui-grid-col-1">
        <p:message for="cmpny" id="company" display="icon" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-5"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Analogous to `execute` associated with `<f:ajax>` is `process` in `<p:ajax>`.

Comment: The same way you'd add a custom message for server side validation

Comment: I am able to show validation error message in this way <p:inputText id="cmpny" value="#{userData.cmpny}" validatorMessage="company name cannot be left blank and must be greater than 2 characters">                                                    <div class="ui-grid-col-7"><p:message for="cmpny" id="company" display="icon,text" /></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-3" align="left">
  <h:outputLabel for="fnm" value="First Name:*" />
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-col-2">
  <p:inputText id="fnm" value="#{userData.fnm}" validatorMessage="First Name cannot be left blank and must be greater than 3 characters" >
    <f:validateLength minimum="4" />
    <p:ajax execute="currentInput" update="firstname" event="blur" process="@this" />
  </p:inputText>                            
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-col-7"><p:message for="fnm" id="firstname" display="icon,text"/></div>
```

With the help of "validatorMessage" attribute,  I am able to show  customized messages when ever the validation fails for the primeface elements like (inputText,calendar etc..,),.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a message bundle via javascript. See [PrimeFacesLocales](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales) for examples.

[PrimeFaces User Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation), 7. Client Side Validation / 7.4 Messages.